# html columns and flexes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to create an input box with a left-aligned button? The button should not be located inside the input box.

I need to create an input box with a button, where the width of both elements fits the size of a div. The input box should be three-fourths of the length, and the button should be one-fourth of the length.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the code you've attempted to solve your question as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
      <input type="submit" />
      <input type="text" />
</div>

<style>

div {
  display: flex;
}

input[type='submit'] {
  width: 25%;
}

input[type='text'] {
  width: 75%;
}

</style>
```

I created a submit button and a text input field and wrapped it inside a div. Next, I did some styling.

I gave div a display of flex which aligns button and input field next to each other.

Then I gave the button a width of 25% or 1/4 of the length of div and gave input field a width of 75% or 3/4 of the length of div.

If you want to give specific width to the div, you can do so by using the width property on the div.